# PHP Undefined Class

Tags: php, json, class, laravel

I am using Laravel and I have a function in my Controller as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Clans;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use App\Helpers\DataTables;


class ClansController extends Controller
{

    public function indexload(){
            $tableData = new DataTables();
            return $tableData->get('clans', 'id', array('id', 'clanid', 'name', 'location', 'level', 'exp', 'warslost', 'warstied', 'warwinpercent', 'warswon','playercount', 'score'));
    }
}
```

DataTables is a Class in `\app\Helpers\`

The page is live at: http://clashdata.tk/clans/load

You can see that the JSON is being displayed like it should but then after the JSON there is a Laravel error saying the class couldn't be found and this is causing problems for my script. How come it says the class can't be found?

The Class is available here: http://pastebin.com/Wpn9u64U

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace in your `DataTables` class is off.

You currently have `namespace App\Helpers\DataTables;`, but it should be: `namespace App\Helpers;`